# Is it possible to change "kendo dataviz" chart type in run time

Tags: c#, javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-dataviz

I have pie chart and I want when I click on the button it would show bar chart. Is it possible to do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, just do:

```
// Get reference to your chart
var chart = $("#chart").data("kendoChart");
// Change type for first serie
chart.options.series[0].type = "bar";
// Finally refresh chart
chart.refresh();
```

See example here : http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/UeWbq/